# Google Search Console Warning: " Indexed, though blocked by robots.txt " (BUG)

Tags: google-search-console, googlebot, search-engine-indexing, robots.txt, crawl-errors

Two days ago I've got an email with a warning from Google Search Console, telling me that 3 URLs from my site **where indexed, but were blocked by** `robots.txt`.

Since I first deployed my website, I haven't changed the `robots.txt` file.

**robots.txt**

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /admin
Disallow: /admin/
Disallow: /blog/search
Disallow: /blog/search/

Sitemap: https://www.example.com/sitemap.xml
```

And these are the pages that I got the warning from:

```
https://www.example.com/blog/slug-1
https://www.example.com/blog/slug-2
https://www.example.com/blog/slug-3
```

I think everyone agrees that those pages are **NOT being blocked by my** `robots.txt` file, right?

**Note:** I have others blogposts with other slugs and they're just fine. No warnings beyond those 3 urls.

Anyway, I clicked the `Fix Issues` button on Google Search Console and they're currently in `pending` state.

Has this happened to anyone before? What could be the cause of this?

---

**UPDATE:**

Infact, I just inspected one of the 3 urls and got this:

[image]

But when I clicked on `Test Live URL`, this is what I get:

[image]

And I'm 100% my `robots.txt` file hasn't changed since I first deployed this website. I.e: **this is 100% a bug from the Googlebot crawling process.**

Answer (score 2):

This exact bug is being reported by others in the Google webmaster forum. It may be an actual bug & you might want to report it there.

Comment: Thank you! Could you give me link of the discussion?