# Google Search Console: issues detected "Top Errors" Server Error (5xx). BUG?

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, googlebot, search-engine-indexing, crawl-errors

Just got this email from Google Search Console:

[image]

This were the issues:

[image]

But when I inspected those live URL's (using Google Search Console tool) they came back as "**available to Google**" and one of them was infact already indexed.

[image]

My app is a Single Page App built with React and Firebase.

I'm doing Server Side Rendering to robots using a Firebase Cloud Function `ssrApp`

There are no errors showing up on my function's logs. Not on those dates (last crawled dates in the screen above), and no other dates.

**QUESTION**

I'm thinking this is a bug from Google Search. Has anyone seen this before?

Recently I got this other email from Google saying that some of my pages were blocked by `robots.txt`, which was clearly a bug (see link below). But the pages are different this time. They are not the same as the ones from the other error.

[Google Search Console Warning: " Indexed, though blocked by robots.txt " (BUG)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/128121/google-search-console-warning-indexed-though-blocked-by-robots-txt-bug)

Comment: FWIW, I run a small web hosting business and have had a couple of the same happen for customers in the last week.  Seems to be a false positive.

Comment: Thanks, Steve! I'm treating this as a false positive also. Since I have no errors on my server's rendering functions.

Answer (score 1):

Server errors (5xx) mean that when the Googlebot tried to crawl those pages, they were unavailable (server was offline, too slow, etc) AT THE TIME MENTIONED; if you tested the live URLs at a later time, it can be that the reason for the server error wasn't present anymore and those pages should be crawled next time Google visits your website (as you mentioned, one of them already was).

If you do get this type of error constantly, then it becomes a problem and you'll need to look deeper into your server load and/or configuration - otherwise, it was probably something temporary.